# solve the differential equation : $(x^2+xy)\frac{dy}{dx}-(3xy+y^2)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(x^2+xy)\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}-(3xy+y^2)=0$

Here is my idea ,  $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=\displaystyle\frac{y}{x}-\displaystyle\frac{2x}{x+y}+2$

Let $t=\displaystyle\frac{y}{x} $ , then

$RHS=t-\displaystyle\frac{2}{1+t}+2$

But I don't know how to do the LHS

Is that a right way to solve this question??

If the idea is wrong , please teach me.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t=\frac{y}{x}$. This implies that $y=tx$ and 
$\frac{dy}{dx}=t+x\frac{dt}{dx}$. Substitute these into the differential equation, we have
$$(x^2+tx^2)\left(t+x\frac{dt}{dx}\right)-(3tx^2+t^2x^2)=0.$$
Divide the whole equation by $x^2$, we have
$$(1+t)\left(t+x\frac{dt}{dx}\right)-(3t+t^2)=0$$
or
$$x\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{3t+t^2}{1+t}-t$$
which can be solved by separation of variables.

Comment: thanks for your help!! I get the answer now^^

Comment: To finish, $\log{x^2} = t + \log{t} + C$, so you have to solve a transcendental equation to compute the function $y(x)$.

Comment: yes , I apply the Lambert W function^^

Answer (score 2):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322791/homogeneous-equation2/322808#322808). Your approach is correct. Here is how to find LHS

$$ y = tx \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = x \frac{dt}{dx}+t. $$

Comment: thanks for your help!! I get the answer now^^

Comment: @cwk709394: You are welcome.