# Homogeneous equation2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

*Please help me to solve this question. Thanks*

Question:

> resolvent Homogeneous equation $=> (x\sin(\frac{y}{x}))dy+(x-y\sin(\frac{y}{x}))dx=0$

My Attempt:
$$
v=\frac{y}{x}\\
y ′=\frac{(y ′ x−y)}{x 2}\\
(x.sin(\frac{(y ′ x−y)}{x 2})dy+(x-y.sin(\frac{(y ′ x−y)}{x 2}))dx
$$
...??? :(

Comment: What is the question here? There's nothing to solve as you only provide a mathematical expression: no equation, ineequality or the like.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: resolvent Homogeneous equation => (x.sin(y x )) dy+(x−y.sin(y x ) )dx=?

Comment: If $v=y/x$, then $v'=(y'x-y)/x^2$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262990/solve-the-differential-equation-x2xy-fracdydx-3xyy2-0/262991#262991). First write the equation as

$$ x\sin(\frac{y}{x})\frac{dy}{dx} +  x-y\sin(\frac{y}{x})=0, $$

then use the substitution

$$ y=xu \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{du}{dx}+u. $$

Now, subs in the ode and simplify.

Comment: Excellent.Can you please help me to solve the following question?

Comment: @flashdesign: You are welcome.